# Add Sum to each worksheet

Tags: excel

I have a workbook which will consist of an inconsistent number of worksheets (so could be <10 or >100 at any given time).

The values column will always be in column G on each and every worksheet.  I have written the following to achieve a total at the bottom of column G in each worksheet:-

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim LR As Long

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For I = 1 To WS_Count

        LR = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("G" & LR + 1).Formula = "=SUM(G4:G" & LR & ")"
        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select

    Next I

End Sub
```

It runs, however once the final worksheet has been totalled, I get the following runtime error:-

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

I've been looking at other threads and applying different approaches, some also work but trigger a **runtime error 91**.

If I place a end or exit to the for statement it fails after processing just one calculation.

I believe the issue lies in `Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select` and falling over when there is no activesheet to process.

Comment: Once you get to the last worksheet in the worksheets collection, trying `worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select` is trying to select something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you norbjd.  I tried a number of titles and this was the only one which was accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get to the last worksheet in the worksheets collection, trying `worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select` is trying to select something that doesn't exist.

Since there is no actual reason to select the worksheet to add a formula, [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251).

```
Dim I As Integer, LR As Long

For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    with ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
        LR = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("G" & LR + 1).Formula = "=SUM(G4:G" & LR & ")"
    end with

Next I
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer.  I will also give this version a go and report back.

Comment: Using the code in this answer worked 100%.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Worksheets in a workbook are a `Collection`.  The good thing about collections is that you can step through each item in the collection using a `For...Each` loop.

The code below will step through each `Worksheet` in the `Worksheets` collection in the workbook that contains the code (`ThisWorkbook`).  You can change this to `ActiveWorkbook` which will do the same for whichever workbook happens to be active at the time.

Rather than return the row number of the last cell in column G the code returns a reference to the actual cell and then `Offset`s by one row to get the next blank row.

`R1C1` style is used for range referencing - `R4C` means row 4 in whichever column the formula is.  `R[-1]C` means the row above the formula in whichever column the formula is in.  So `R4C:R[-1]C` placed in cell `G8` would mean `G4:G7`.

```
Sub WorkSheetLoop()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rLastCell As Range

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set rLastCell = wrkSht.Cells(wrkSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)
        If rLastCell.Row > 4 Then
            rLastCell.Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R4C:R[-1]C)"
        End If
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

**Why your version doesn't work**
The reason why you're getting runtime error #9 is because your code is trying to select a sheet that doesn't exist.

For example, your code starts with the first sheet selected in a two sheet workbook:

Loop 1:

- `LR` is found for the first sheet.
- The `SUM` formula is added to the first sheet.
- The second sheet is selected.

Loop 2:

- `LR` is found for the second sheet.
- The `SUM` formula is added to the second sheet.
- The code attempts to select the third sheet which doesn't exist - error occurs.

Your code would work if you removed the `Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select` line and added `Worksheets(I).Select` as the first line in your loop.

Also, your code can start with any sheet selected - if the last sheet is active when the code starts then it will add the sum to that sheet and then try and select the next sheet causing it to fail on the first loop.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this.  I will give this a go and get back to you.

Comment: This piece of advice made my code work as I expected it to work; thank you again for the advice and explanation.  "Your code would work if you removed the Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select line and added Worksheets(I).Select as the first line in your loop."

Comment: It's generally better to avoid `Select` & `Active...`.  It reduces the amount of screenflicker (to a point where you don't really need `Application.ScreenUpdating=False`) and it doesn't matter what sheet/book/range is selected when the code starts.